# incorrected datetime.now result

Tags: python, django

I have set

```
 TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Copenhagen'
 USE_TZ = True
```

in settings.py. But datetime.now() shows -1 hour then the Copenhagen time zone, what can be wrong? I use python 2,7 Django 1,5. and the web application is running on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

The [`django.utils.timezone.now()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) returns a *timezone aware* `datetime` object, using the UTC timezone.

UTC differs by exactly one hour from Europe/Copenhagen; you can display this `datetime` object in your own timezone if you so desire, but you do need to 'translate' the value to your own timezone explicitly.

Use the [`django.utils.timezone.localtime()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime) to do so:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

print localtime(yourdt)
```